# React.NET uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I am trying to learn ReactJs and found React.NET.

Followed the tutorial on the author's [website](http://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial.html) with the only change being an MVC 5 app instead of MVC 4.

Here is the jsx:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <CommentList data={this.props.data} />
        <CommentForm />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.renderComponent(
  <CommentBox data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);


var CommentList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function (comment) {
      return <Comment author={comment.Author}>{comment.Text}</Comment>;
    });
    return (
      <div className="commentList">
        {commentNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});


var CommentForm = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentForm">
        Hello, world! I am a CommentForm.
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var data = [
  { Author: "Daniel Lo Nigro", Text: "Hello ReactJS.NET World!" },
  { Author: "Pete Hunt", Text: "This is one comment" },
  { Author: "Jordan Walke", Text: "This is *another* comment" }
];
```

It gives this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

[image: Error in console]

Any clues on this one?

Regards.

Comment: Looking at the tutorial, should it be `<CommentList data={this.props.data} />`?

Answer (score 2):

There are three steps in the snippet.

First, define the `CommentBox`:

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass...
```

Second, render the `CommentBox` and the `CommentList`:

```
React.renderComponent...
```

Third, define the `CommentList`:

```
var CommentList = React.createClass...
```

So, the problem is that the `CommentList` is rendered before the `CommentList` is defined. If the last two steps were switched around then it would work fine. The `CommentList` class needs to be defined before it can be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

CommentForm is also defined in the wrong place - it needs to be defined before it's referred to. The React tutorial has it the wrong way round: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html

The correct order for the definition of the classes in the Javascript is:

```
var Comment = React.createClass

...
var CommentList = React.createClass

...
var CommentForm = React.createClass

...
var CommentBox = React.createClass

...
```

Comment: And another thing the authors of the tutorial forgot to add: in the html file, instead of   <script type="text/jsx">   you need  <script type="text/jsx" src="/tutorial.js"> (depending on where you put tutorial.js)

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen whilst working through the tutorial and found that declaring the var data = [...] at the top of the jsx script resolved the issue. So it would appear that the engine is not hoisting variables properly?